# How would a new species of homo replace humans in my world?

Tags: evolution, humans, apocalypse

In some place in the world a new species of homo evolved (probably from homo sapiens). Let's call the species *Homo futurus*.

As a new species they can not have fertile children with humans. They may look like very similar to humans but they **are** different creatures may be because of how their brain works. And evolutionary they have some superior features than humans so they can able to replace humans. They are motivated and hard coded to replace humans. They may be very peaceful creatures, but existence is the most important thing for them.

What would be the new species *Homo futurus*'s features and strategy so that they can successfully survive and replace humans in human dominated world?

My initial idea is:

- They physically look very similar to humans and hide, populate, control key positions in human society using their higher cognitive abilities like better intelligence, organization, communication skills with better emotional control.
- But how would they hide their DNA difference?
- How would they successfully replace human population in world, butchering all of them? Fertility control?
- Would they able to live with humans or they need to totally exterminate them for their existence.

Comment: Either *Homo relictus* or *Homo reliquus* would be more plausible scientific names. (Or, more distant, *Homo relicitus*, *Homo relicinus*...) Specific attributes don't get an initial capital, and I cannot find a plausible derivation for _*relicus_ for a Latin or Greek stem. And if there is a scientific name for this species it means that its existence is _known_, isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Gorkem*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Ignoring the flaws in the concept, I think this is still a fine amount of them and you didn't ask about it, why do you think their strategy for taking over the world would be different from the strategy any other group would have? I don't get that from your question. Also you are asking about them to "survive and prosper" and then about "replace humans". I don't think they are identical. I also do not know if they are hiding or taking over or what they are doing? Are you looking for like a plan for the next 1000 years in stages?

Comment: well i have no latin knowledge and i want to say "future" in latin and googled it. i make it relicum but i am open for better suggestions. they are different from other groups because they can not reproduce with humans. also they are in someway superior than humans so they can able to replace humans

Comment: In what way are they superior? Many humans are superior to me in many ways but nobody tries to replace me.  And what is the advantage they have from that superiority that is so huge they have to and can take over the world? Also please note that "not reproduce" isn't that big of a deal in such a complex society as ours and on top of that nobody would notice if I for example wasn't able to reproduce with any other person but my wife ... I'm not saying this question is bad btw, I'm just saying it is for now identical with "how to take over the world"

Comment: "Future man" would be *Homo futurus* or possibly *H. posterior*. Re-bid or re-proposed man would be *H. relicitus*; and there is nothing wrong with *H. novus* or *H. novior*. There is a great Latin and Greek dictionary online at [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/search); you can search in many ways, using the sections "Dictionary entry lookup" and "English to language lookup"; you are expected to have a minimal grasp of Latin and Greek grammar, though.

Comment: I don't believe that this concept makes any sense. Where to they come from? There would not suddenly be 100 members of another species around the globe who need to organize. Evolution starts with small things and these changes would probably become part of the larger human gene pool. You would need very selective breeding to limit some traits to a specific gene line and thus produce a new species (after many, many, many, many, many ... many generations). Before that, you simply have humans with specific, inherited traits (who can still interbreed with other humans).

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz is correct. Your new species will need to be reproductively isolated from _Homo sapiens_ for many generations, at least thousands of years and probably tens or hundreds of thousands, before their genes have drifted enough that they're not inter-fertile.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I agree, but I have to defend Gorkem. A lightsaber or an Orc army with horrible military strategy doesn't make sense either. If it made sense, it would almost certainly exist. I advice you to check out the horrific "Amazing spiderman" series with Emma Stone or something. Nothing makes sense there but still Emma Stone is rich. As I stated in my comment I would argue that this is still a fine level of nonsense

Comment: I changed the structure of the question hope it is more clear now. How they evolved is irrelevant I guess as they evolved how a millions of new species evolved.  the answer can be this cant happen ever but i want to know why.

Comment: The important question is not answered: Where did they come from? How did they start? This will determine much of what follows. How did they evolve from humans (with means breeding with humans) without their genes becoming part of the larger gene pool? Were they artificially created? How? When? Yesterday? A thousand years ago?

Comment: It seems evolution of a species can occur only in small steps(correct me if I am wrong) so it is not possible just to have a very different creature in one step. this is weak point i guess. you may need thousands years of isolated cult like structures i guess :) or may be you use a tech that makes genetically modified humans

Answer (score 4):

First off - this reminds me of a TV show where there was a hidden organisation of human variant - detailed here: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Prey_(TV_series).

There is not a lot to go on in your question - but my initial impression is that there will be little trouble based on the genetic difference - it's just not  obvious enough to provoke a visceral reaction. Additionally the current 'official' social approach in the west is that discriminating on something like genetics is un-PC. Add to this the low understanding of genetics.

Your new species is smart and diligent, meaning that they are going to end up gravitating to positions of responsibility if they want them. This brings wealth, they can afford large families, etc. This seems to be just a matter of time.

We don't have a solid definition of human, and it could be reasonable to argue - with the approaching explosion of gene-based medicine - that we might find different 'species' of human. The trick would be to have your new 'species' included in the definition of human in law so that regular humans do not see them as competition.

Other more pressing problems:

Recognition - given their very low numbers, how will they find and recognise each other?

Collaboration - this is a difficult point - why do they care about their group? Humans are motivated to survive, but are by no means peaceful with respect to each other. Your new species seem to be 'artificially' cohesive as a group, how is this mediated?

Physiology - humans are a diverse bunch - how much of the population are going to be able to tell something is 'not right' with the new species? Geneticist, surgeon, nurse, dentist, barber? How 'weird' are they? How much work do they have to do to appear normal - and do they even know how different they are?

From a story point of view

- What normal activities are easy/hard to do, and why?
- Are the new species all decedents of a single person, or are they emerging due to some other factor - common mutation, virus incorporation into humans, pollutant, artificial meddling, etc. Remember most mutations just kill you, so the origin may be important to see where things go.
- Your question indicates that there is a push to speed things up (which changes the tone of the story a bit) in which case it may be an idea to consider accelerating the process:

  - Gain influence/control over the gene related technologies and regulation
  - Consider compromising infertility treatment and reproductive medicine centres with fertilised eggs provided by the new species
  - Ensure that all members of the new species are well resourced - scholarships, business funding etc.

At this point you are getting into 'hiding a large conspiracy' territory, which is very difficult. It might be useful to make this 'necessary' by adding in a danger or time limit for the new species which means that they *must* grow quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If your new species had emerged a few hundred years ago, there might be a concern that inter-species warfare was unavoidable; but this is the age of genetic manipulation.  Over the course of the next few hundred years, hundreds (if not thousands) of new  human species will emerge, each handcrafted by a talented genetic scientist in pursuit of a particular set of enhancements.

Your naturally occurring evolutionary variant will just be one more in the crowd.

By the time your Homo Futurus reproduce to an adequate population level and are ready to "come out of the closet", they will not be alone.  Vanilla humanity will have had to grow out of its species-centrist prejudices.  Either that, or face an ever growing menagerie of superior enemies.

Natural evolution is over!  From here on, humanity will drive its own genetic destiny.

Comment: "Vanilla humanity" will be one of my favourite terms from now on in the context of questions like this one

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all you omitted very crucial thing: How did they discover they are different from humans?

You have two choices:

1. Their difference is noticed by humans (which is bad as they could keep them for scientific reasons and you would have *Golden Man* by Philip K. Dick)
2. They live outside the society but still close to notice the change by themselves.

The second case gives them the upper hand in regards to the element of surprise and time. But, as you noticed, they may be smarter than humans and are peaceful. So they can still live in some place without anyone noticing.

For all we know Canadians can be *Homo superiori*. Or Swiss people. Which close your problem as solved.
Because even if regular humans discover superiority of that one country your people just can go **TADAAAA**  and show the chemical weapon that could erase all and only humans. So don't try to flock with them. Ever.
Oh, and by the way: They don't even need the weapon. They just show and tell.

Comment: Well because they all understand the quantum field theory at age 10. they understand things that humans can never understand, they can create and solve puzzles humans can not understand, so it easy to identify themselves i guess

Comment: @Gorkem, so they're both easy identifiable but able to hide among baseline people at the same time?

Comment: @Gorkem Creating and solving puzzle people don't understand are very common for 10 year old kids. It's called Calvinball. If you have a one kid that understand quantum field theory it is very smart (nothing special). If you have a large group of such smart kids out of nowhere you may have stepped into North Korea school for export children.

Comment: They are peaceful, they don't want to kill all the humans.

Comment: of course people can create puzzles or words or languages that others can not understand because of a missing information. but if you are able to observe it, you can figure out . but there are problems that how much time you spend observing only some talented people can figure out. like problems in quantum theory

Comment: There is a youtube movie when some Japanese guy spend 15 years solving the ring puzzle. Which he didn't solve. So was he not a homo sapiens?